# Elementary Obj-C Question bout Methods

Tags: objective-c, methods

take example:

```
-(void)setName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age;
```

How would you call this method (in other words, the method's name is setName but what is the "age" parameter doing in there) and what do the types in parentheses mean? Is it just a way to tell the compiler what types are being returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ myObject setName: @"Adam" age:18 ];`

The `age` parameter is the second parameter in the method signature.

The types in parentheses are the expected types for the argument. e.g. `name` is expecting only an `NSString` and `age` is expecting only an `int`.

The `-` means that the method is an instance method, not a class method, which is denoted using a `+` instead.

The type in parentheses right after the `-` is the return type.

This is a great site for learning the basics of Objective-C: [CocoaDevCentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard Objective-C method syntax.  This could be read as:

> A method with no return value (void) that
>   sets the name of the object (an NSString * parameter)
>   and the age (and integer
>   parameter).

Dissecting the method:

- "-" The hyphen states that this is an instance method.
- (void) The return type is void - or
  no return type expected
- setName:(NSString *) The first
  parameter to be passed is the "name"
  and is an NSString *.
- age:(int)age    The second parameter
  to be passed is    the "age" and is
  an int.

In reality, the method syntax is actually quite self-documenting once understood (and quite foreign if you're used to more tradition C/C++ or Java syntax).

The actual example of the call of this method would be:

```
[someObject setName:@"Rich" age:101];
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer, one would need a bit more information, but I'll be guessing this is from some sort of class named aClass, and you have an instance of aClass, named instance.

```
-(void)setName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age;
```

means you have a method, named setName:age:, that needs two arguments, one NSString, one int, and it returns a void. As it has a - as it's first character, it is an instance method.

```
[instance setName:@"James Hargrove" age:21];
```

Would call setName:age: on the instance.

(The instance should be created using, say,

```
aClass *instance = [[aClass alloc] init];
```

which would create an instance of aClass named instance, and initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

The method name is actually this:

```
setName:age:
```

You call it like this:

```
[someObject setName:@"Alice" age:20];
```

`setName:age:` is also the unique signature of that method, and with that signature you can call that method on any object you wish.  For example:

```
NSArray* objects = ...

SEL mySelector = @selector(setName:age:);
for (id object in objects)
{
    if ([object respondsToSelector:mySelector])
    {
        [object setName:@"Alice" age:20];
    }
}
```

> what do the types in parentheses mean? Is it just a way to tell the compiler what types are being returned?

Yes, those are "C casts".  If everything was an object you wouldn't need those, but because you can pass and return plain old C types to and from your methods, the compiler needs to know the types of your parameters and return values.

Answer (score 0):

You'd call this method like so:

```
[classInstance setName:@"name" age:123];
```

The first instance of "age:" indicates that the method receives another parameter, called "age" when used in the implementation of the method.

The types in parentheses indicate the types of data that are expected for each parameter, with the exception of the first one, "void", which means that this method returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So, you would call this method as follows.

Say it is a method of an object named foo (of class Foo). Then you would call:

```
[foo setName:someName age:someAge].
```

If it were a static method, it would be preceded by a + instead of a minus as follows:

```
+(void)setName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age;
```

Then you would call

```
[Foo setName:someName age:someAge] //use the classname instead of the object name
```

The types are indeed there for type-checking by the compiler. You'll get warnings if you pass the wrong sort of data, and you will get warnings if your header doesn't match your implementation.

You can actually write Obj-C functions in a couple of different styles though, omitting some of this stuff. You can even write straight up C-style.